# Laravel : pivot table point to multiple tables

Tags: pivot, laravel-5

lets say i have an `orders` table that is going to have a many-to-many relation to three other tables named `typings`, `translates` and  `theses` .  I know pivot table should be somehow like [many to many polymorphic relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) but that is not exactly what im looking for.
how should i implement pivot table?

Comment: Isn't a many-to-many polymorphic exactly what you're looking for? That's the purpose of that relation.

Comment: Ok ,regarding to Laravel documentation example ,would you please tell how may i access to related posts via a video through many-to-many polymorphic and vice versa? and what about  having another table named `books` in addition to `posts` and `videos`?

Comment: I've added the implementation as an answer. In the Laravel example - posts are not related to videos -- they may only share common tags. In which case, you can get the tags from a post, then loop through those retrieving the videos from each tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create a polymorphic relationship with orders and the other three tables through a pivot table named `orderables`

```
// TABLES NEEDED
orders
  id - integer

typings
  id - integer

translates
  id - integer

theses
  id - integer

orderables
  order_id - integer
  orderable_id - integer
  orderable_type - string


// MODELS/RELATIONSHIPS NEEDED
class Typing extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Order', 'orderable');
    }
}
class Translate extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Order', 'orderable');
    }
}
class Thesis extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Order', 'orderable');
    }
}
class Order extends Model
{
    public function typings()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Typing', 'orderable');
    }
    public function translates()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Translate', 'orderable');
    }
    public function theses()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Thesis', 'orderable');
    }
}
```

Then, you could get the orders of a model like this:

```
$thesis = Thesis::find(1);
$orders = $thesis->orders;
```

And the inverse:

```
$order = Order::find(1);
$theses = $order->theses;
```

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate the differences between `morphMany` , `morphToMany` , `morphByMany` ?

Comment: `morphMany` is the method to define a one-to-many polymorphic relationship. Such as a `like` -- suppose we have a `Post` model and a `Comment` model and a user should be able to `Like` either. Well, a user can only `Like` a post once, but she can `Like` a comment as well.

Comment: `morphToMany` and `morphByMany` define a many-to-many polymorphic relationship. Such as a `tag` -- using the same example as above, a user can `Tag` a `Post` with many tags and can `Tag` many different posts with the same tags. She can also do the same with `Comments`.